# What would cause my Silverlight .xap to quadruple in size suddenly?

Tags: silverlight, xap

I've been working on a Silverlight application.
**I just noticed that the .xap file is now four times as big as it was, what could have caused that?**

Here's some other info:

- there seems to now be many **more language settings** in the bin/Release directory
- I checked "Reduce size of .xap" in under Properties/Silverlight but that just brought it down from 1300 to 1200.
- I reference the **System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit** dll but I was doing that even when it was 325K

Screenshot of build directories before and after:

[image]
<sub>(source: [deviantsart.com](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/qdvpic.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since .xap is just a zip file, rename the .xap file to .zip and open it up and take a look at the files contained. Perhaps you added a large resource inadvertently?

Comment: I renamed, unzipped and found I was including a folder I didn't need, nice to know, thanks!